# The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption on WAS

Tags: sql-server, ssl, jdbc, websphere, tls1.2

Websphere 8.5 on Linux environment is used with java 7. SSL TLS 1.2 is enabled on the WAS server. The sql jdbc jar used is 6.4 . I am to successfully test the datasource connection on WAS. TLS1.2 is also enabled on the SQL Server 2016. Currently the jdbc url is as follows that is used:

```
"jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;" +
"databaseName=AdventureWorks;" +
"encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;sslProtocol=TLSv1.2";
```

But when I am making connection through jndi ie. 
    datasource.getConnection(DatabaseName) ,
 the above error comes. 
    I am able to make connection through Driver Manager as well.

Comment: What if you set `trustServerCertificate=true`?

Comment: I have also tried this.. still same error is coming.

Comment: The javax.sql.DataSource interface has no method signature for getConnection() that takes a database name (or a single String for that matter).  How are you obtaining the datasource?